# Place plain text file in shared local drive

Tags: apex, activedirectory

I know that we can generate text file using Salesforce.However my requirement is to generate the text file daily and place it in server directory.Let say that this is to enable external program to read the file automatically from server directory.

Honestly, I would like to have that external program to communicate directly to Salesforce instead placing the file in server directory because that make more sense.But just in case, is it possible to read or upload file to Server Directory  using Apex?Or do I need to use special tool do do that?

Comment: yes you can use Batch/Schedule apex to do this.

Comment: @TusharSharma , sorry I have updated my question to be more specific. If possible , may I know what API for this.

Comment: after creating the file you can also use a tool like data loader to export the file and place it in the correct directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afaik there really isn't a "server directory", considering that salesforce is a distributed cloud service with a large number of shared server nodes. Since these are shared servers, there's no chance that any customer would be able to modify files on them.

Frankly, I wouldn't want anyone to be able to arbitrability upload files onto those shared servers, it's too much of a risk for zero gain.

There's a bunch of other places to store your files, which can be shared between members of your org:

- Files
- Salesforce CRM Content
- Salesforce Knowledge
- Documents
- Attachments

You can read about the differences between these file storage methods [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_files_differences.htm&type=5).

I suggest you use one which meets your business needs, and is provided by the platform, instead of trying to access functionality not provided to developers. If you're still insistent on providing a file on a server somewhere, you'd be a lot better off hosting the server yourself.

Comment: The reason why I am asking is there requirement whereby external program that is not reside in cloud would like to read the file automatically in server and process the data from there.

Comment: By providing the program with login info, maybe an oauth token or other method, you might be able to get it to log into salesforce and locate the correct file- but thats making a lot of assumptions. It's very likely you'll have to write some custom code (Either in Salesforce or by modifying your program) to support this functionality, which might be out of your skill set.